# return distinct text which is longtext format (but not returning the repeated text)

Tags: mysql

I have a simple scenario as follow:

I have 2 column : 1) id and 2) text(which is long text format)

I use the simple query to extract all info from mysql as follow:

```
select id,text from dbtest
```

but the problem is for different id I might have the same text but in retrieval time I do not want to return  rows with the same text again and again so I do not want to return the repeated texts,I tried to use distinct but it was not working,

How can I do that , any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use user-defined variables:

```
select id, 
  @text:=if(@text=text, '', text) text
from dbtest, (select @text:='') t
order by text
```

- [SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2e95/2)

I would generally recommend doing this on the application side rather than the database though.

Comment: Thank you how can I just show the first one among all repeated one, because in the code that you write you return the second repeated text as null, for example is it possible to just return 2 some more text and not return 3

Comment: That's a different question altogether :) -- But yes, you can do it a couple ways -- with `group by text`, you get a random result.  With this, you can order your result somewhat.  Here's an updated fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2e95/11

Answer (score 1):

Distinct works on all selected columns. You must use a GROUP  BY:

```
SELECT id,text FROM dbtest GROUP BY text
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have two questions, can you post the code you are using for us? And are some of the fields for the text empty?

The query might be detecting a "Null" kind of event in which if the field is empty, it repeats the last one because the variable might not be getting unset. In which case you might just want to unset your variables at the end of your (I'm assuming) while loop.

Comment: Please take a look at question again I corrected and clarify some parts to make it more clear the thing is I have many rows and some of them contains exactly the same text for example row 1 has hello and row 2 has hello as well what I want to do is to write a query  to return just one hello instead of 2 to avoid returning repeated text.

Comment: Hmm, that's a toughie. You might want to try running a query by selecting the distinct text, then inside that, run another query where you get all the info from the table where the text=text. If you need a better explanation I can put it on a page and give the link.